# Typescript Class with Express Mounted Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, class

**Trying to convert a Node.js project that uses Express.js.**
The end goal is something similar to what I've already got in the App.ts file. In vanilla Javascript, the solution is the same, but instead of a class, it's a module.exports variable function.

```js
export class UserRouter {
    constructor() {}

    // Open to all users
    register() {
        router.post('/account-register', AuthController.prototype.register);
    }
    login() {
        router.post('/account-login', AuthController.prototype.login);
    }
    logout() {
        router.get('/account-logout', AuthController.prototype.logout);
    }
    forgotPassword() {
        router.post(
            '/account-password-forgot',
            AuthController.prototype.forgotPassword
        );
    }
    resetPassword() {
        router.patch(
            '/account-password-reset/:token',
            AuthController.prototype.resetPassword
        );
    }
    // Require Login for all subsequent routes
    protectedRoutes() {
        router.use(AuthController.prototype.protectedRoutes);
    }

    updateUserProfile() {
        this.protectedRoutes;
        router.patch(
            '/account-update-profile',
            UserController.prototype.uploadUserPhoto,
            UserController.prototype.updateMyProfile
        );
    }
    updateUserSettings() {
        this.protectedRoutes;
        router.patch(
            '/account-update-settings',
            UserController.prototype.updateUserSettings
        );
    }
    deactivateUserAccount() {
        this.protectedRoutes;
        router.delete(
            '/account-deactivate',
            UserController.prototype.deactivateUser
        );
    }
    // Only the delcared user roles can access the subsequent routes
    limitedAccessByUserRole() {
        router.use(
            AuthController.prototype.restrictToRoles(
                'employee-admin',
                'employee-super-admin'
            )
        );
    }
    getAllUsers() {
        this.protectedRoutes;
        this.limitedAccessByUserRole;
        router.route('/').get(UserController.prototype.getAllUsers);
    }
    createUser() {
        this.protectedRoutes;
        this.limitedAccessByUserRole;
        router.route('/').post(UserController.prototype.createUser);
    }
    getUser() {
        this.protectedRoutes;
        this.limitedAccessByUserRole;
        router.route('/:id').get(UserController.prototype.getUser);
    }
    updateUser() {
        this.protectedRoutes;
        this.limitedAccessByUserRole;
        router.route('/:id').patch(UserController.prototype.updateUser);
    }
    deleteUser() {
        this.protectedRoutes;
        this.limitedAccessByUserRole;
        router.route('/:id').delete(UserController.prototype.deleteUser);
    }
}
```

The class was imported into the App.ts file with the variable `UserRouter`.

```js
// Mounted API Routes
const apiVersion = '1.0';
const apiRoutes = `/api/v${apiVersion}`;
app.use(`${apiRoutes}/users`, UserRouter);
```

Looking for a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated. Full project code (minus ENV files) is on [Github](https://github.com/fortembr/pawn-markdown/tree/v0.0.2-api).

Comment: Changing to typescript has nothing to do with adding classes

Comment: @AluanHaddad, fair. I didn't really start to understand classes until I picked up TS.

Comment: Yeah, it's important to understand classes come from JavaScript. Otherwise you won't understand them.

Comment: The issue here seems to be that you can't use "new UserRouter" as the app.use() middleware. Trying to work through it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a class property with all the routes, something like this.

user.network.ts

```js
export default class UserRoutes {
    public router: Router;

   // remplace my controller for your controller
    private controller: UserController = new UserController();

    constructor() {
        this.router = express.Router();
        this.registerRoutes();
    }

   // remplace my example routes and controller methods for your own 
    protected registerRoutes(): void {
        this.router.get('/:username',this.controller.getUserByUsername);
        this.router.get('/', this.controller.paginationByUsername);
        this.router.post('/', this.controller.createUser);
        this.router.post('/login', this.controller.login);
        this.router.put('/', this.controller.editUser);
    }
}
```

routes.js

```js
import express from 'express';
import UserRouter from './userRoutes.ts'

// if you want to add another router like news or something else
// you could add one 'server.use(...)' below the 'server.use('/user',...)

const routes = (server:express.Application): void => {
    server.use('/user', new UserRoute().router);
};

export default routes
```

In server.js you could have something like this.

```js
class Server {
    public app: express.Application;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.config();
    }

    public config(): void {
        this.app.set('port', 3000);
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
        routes(this.app)
    }

    public start(): void {
        this.app.listen(this.app.get('port'), () => {
            console.log('Server listening in port 3000');
        });
    }
}

const server = new Server();
server.start();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).